# How can in compress the mysqldump with Python Popen

Tags: python, ubuntu, compression

I am using command to dump the database

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("mysqldump -e --opt --skip-lock-tables  --skip-extended-insert -c %s > %s" % (database, filename), shell=True)
```

But it produces sql file

is there any to compress to make `tar.gz` from the same command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gzip` for compression. Then the command for `Popen()` looks like:

```
"mysqldump -e --opt --skip-lock-tables  --skip-extended-insert -c %s | gzip > %s.gz"
```

It produces a `.gz` file with the same compression rate as `.tar.gz`. You don't need to build a `.tar` archive as you have just a single file.